# Split a string from a textfile correctly

Tags: python, string

i have a file ("text.txt") with several lines (~5000000 lines). I'm trying to split a line so that:

```
2   :   :   PUNCT   sent    _   _   _   _   _3-4    L'Algebra   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
```

becomes this two lines:

```
2   :   :   PUNCT   sent    _   _   _   _   _
3-4 L'Algebra   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
```

so essentially i want to transform a single line into two lines and write it back to another file. All the lines that has to be split starts with the character "*" (underscore) and a number or number+"-"+number. I want to split the line into two lines after the character "*" (underscore).

If i try to split the line with this function:

```
lines = re.split("_\d")
```

and write the list lines to a file after i get this:

```
2   :   :   PUNCT   sent    _   _   _   _   _
-4 L'Algebra   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
```

How can i get to do this correctly? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `re.split()` here, because it consumes the split token.  Instead I think you want to replace `_\d` with `_\n\d`.

Comment: Also, are you sure that output is correct?  Your input has five underscores before the split, and the output retains all five underscores on the first line.  I would have expected the fifth underscore to be consumed as part of the split token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> re.split("_(?=\d+)", line)

['2   :   :   PUNCT   sent    _   _   _   _   ',
 "3-4    L'Algebra   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _"]
```